# ruby on rails tutorial chapter 7 issue displaying sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am having an issue when going through chapter 7 of the 3rd edition of ruby on rails tutorial.

I am trying to create the sign in page and keep getting an error message when I am trying to     display the page.

**this is the error message**

`Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5     raised:`

```
`Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
  (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
Extracted source (around line #5):`
```

`<html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", 
                                                    "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

**also the error message when running the rake test is below**

```
{ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 0.379314557]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (0.38s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 0.432734702]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.43s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
          (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 0.472730828]
 test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (0.47s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.51867541]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.52s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_contact", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.773771717]
 test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.77s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in      `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
       test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.807242051]
 test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.81s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected     "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

 ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.838956398]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.84s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
      (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185)
        app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:185
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2473502046027579375_42591780'
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in     <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

  16/16: [========] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.84354s
16 tests, 17 assertions, 0 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips}
```

**this is the custom sytle sheet**

```
`@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
-moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing:         border-box;
 }


   /* universal */

 html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  }

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
 overflow: auto;
 }

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3em;
letter-spacing: -2px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-medium-light;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
   }

 /* miscellaneous */

 .debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
   margin-top: 45px;
   @include box_sizing;
 }

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section.user_info {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
     display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.gravatar_edit {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}`
```

**and this is the application.html.erb file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", 
                                              "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the other pages that have been created/setup since the end of chapter 6 are all ok.

can anyone see the error of my ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom.css.scss:

```
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
   }
  } <--!!!
```

You forgot to close braces.